# How can I register new user and prevent admin to know user's keys [Hyperledger Fabric]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Is it possible to do that?

I know that we can [sign transactions offline](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-sign-transaction-offline.html) before send to network, this process make user's keys totally private even for admin. But can I do the same with register? And If I can do it, can I do it on browser?

Answer (score 0):

Registration and enrollment are separate actions.  Of course if an admin registers a user, they will likely know the enroll ID and secret and *could* potentially enroll as the user.  But in the case where the user enrolls, the client/user has the private key; it is not shared with the admin.